# CANopen/CAN bus, what do I need, including a protocol (OD?), to communicate between PC terminal and CAN device module

Tags: c, embedded, network-protocols, can-bus

I have a dsPIC33 with ECAN and wish to establish a protocol (using [SDO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen#Service_Data_Object_.28SDO.29_protocol) if possible) in such way that it communicate between terminal software and dsPIC33 where I can perform diagnostics within dsPIC33 and supporting ICs.

I do not know what is required, so what is a low cost way of doing this? I could use a CAN-to-USB device, but I am unsure if this will work. What kind of protocol inside CANUSB wraps around the ASCII-based message?

What hardware can I use? Can it be used to monitor the CAN bus as well? I do not wish to invest in an expensive setup as in Vector or similar heavy-weight solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download [an open source project for CANopen from DATALINK ENGINEERING](http://datalink.se/index5.php) as this seems to be just what you need.

Answer (score 5):

When you purchase CAN interface hardware, it does not typically include software to work with specific upper-level CAN protocols (like CANopen).  They do usually come with a set of DLL files that allow you to write custom PC applications to interface with your hardware.

If you do not want to purchase any third-party software, then you must:

1. Implement a basic CAN driver for the dsPIC33 (transmit and receive a basic frame).
2. Implement the CANopen SDO protocol on top of your basic driver on the dsPIC33.
3. Purchase a [low-cost CAN<->USB interface](http://www.softing.com/home/en/automotive-electronics/products/can-bus/interface-cards/can/usb.php) (which should come with DLLs that allow you to develop in C, C++ or C#.
4. Write a PC application using the DLL files which implements the CANopen SDO protocol.

You may want to look for open-source implementations of the protocol. One such implementation is [CanFestival](http://www.canfestival.org/). However, I have never used this library.

Comment: I had look into CanFestival and download TortoiseHg but I have no clue how to download the respostory within CanFestival (http://dev.automforge.net/CanFestival-3/summary)

Comment: The link you provided is the link to the Mercurial repo.  If you have TortoiseHg installed, then the clone URL you want is `http://dev.automforge.net/CanFestival-3`.  From the command-line you could type `hg clone http://dev.automforge.net/CanFestival-3`